# Cloudflare Rocket loader blocking JS

Tags: cloudflare, rocket-loader

I want to use rocket loader on my page, but when it is on when you come to the page for very first time script freeze and works correctly after refreshing.

After entering the page for the first time, to the page 3 scripts from cloudflare are added at the end of the body:

> 

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7089c43e/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="48c287fd36069ba2003e0917-|49" defer="" type="fa3629c76fee0735b80f7744-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7089c43e/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="fa3629c76fee0735b80f7744-|49" defer=""></script>
>
```

last 2 scripts with different ID block each other and because of this our scripts don't load.

Any ideas how I may fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just use this in your script tag
to disable rocket-loader on this page

```
<script data-cfasync="false">
```